# Cisco AnyConnect: pause connection, or give it lower priority than other vpns

Tags: networking, vpn, cisco-anyconnect

I have to use 2 vpns at work:

1. To access clients network - which has git server inside. It can only be accessed from inside network, and not the internet. It uses simple vpn.
2. To access corporate network - which has tasks, issues and wiki inside. It can only be accessed from its network, too. This one requires using Cisco AnyConnect with 12-digit dynamically generated passwords/SNS authentication.

Problem is that second VPN is always at the end of the pipe. So, if both vpns run simultaneously, I get the routes inside the second network and IP of second VPN.

Is there a workaround for this? For example, it would be nice to rearrange their priorities, because I can turn on and off first VPN without verification. Or ability to halt Cisco AnyConnect VPN, so I could turn it back on without having to enter password later.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing prevents you to uninstall the routes at the terminal level with the route command. You can do it that way easily with a script.

Comment: Can you suggest how?

Comment: Open a command prompt with admin rights in Windows. Type "Route print". You'll see all the routes. You can add or remove routes to certain interfaces as you see fit.

Comment: This may not always work as VPN services usually register for routing table notifications with OS. When such changes are notified by OS, VPN service will restore the routes configured by the VPN server admin (i.e., tunnel all, split include/exclude etc.,). If VPN services don't do that, then we are leaking traffic which defeats the whole purpose of VPN.